# Java for loop error, first item repeating

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am having an issue with my code that calculates an integer for the hand total in a game of Black Jack. For some reason the for loop is iterating the first time through twice, meaning that it uses i = 0 twice through the loop before incrementing i. Is there a reason why it is doing this? I don't know what to change.

```
  private void setTotal(){
    boolean ace = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<hand.size(); i++){
        if((hand.get(i).getValue()) == 1){
            handTotal += 1;
            ace = true;
        }
        else if((hand.get(i).getValue()) > 10){
            handTotal += 10;
        }
        else {
            handTotal += (hand.get(i).getValue());
        }
    }
    if(ace == true && handTotal<12){
        handTotal += 10;
    }
}
```

Below is the code with a bunch of print statements I've been using to check it.

```
   private void setTotal(){
    boolean ace = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<hand.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("start " + i);
        if((hand.get(i).getValue()) == 1){
            handTotal += 1;
            ace = true;
            System.out.println("ace one");
        }
        else if((hand.get(i).getValue()) > 10){
            handTotal += 10;
            System.out.println("face card");
        }
        else {
            handTotal += (hand.get(i).getValue());
            System.out.println("num");
        }
        System.out.println("end " + i);
    }
    if(ace == true && handTotal<12){
        handTotal += 10;
        System.out.println("ace plus");
    }
```

}

In the main, I run this

```
public class BlackJack {

public static void main(String[] args){
   Deck deck = new Deck();
   Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
   deck.shuffle();
   for(int i =0; i<2; i++){
       dealer.dealCard(deck.draw());
   }
   System.out.println(dealer.getHand());
   System.out.println(dealer.getHand().size());
   System.out.println(dealer.getTotal());
}
```

}

And for example it printed 
start 0
num
end 0
start 0
num
end 0
start 1
num
end 1
[7 of Clubs, 4 of Clubs]
2
18

Comment: Which value do you get in hand.size() at first iteration?

Comment: Are you sure it's iterating twice with i = 1 ? or you get handTotal increased twice?

Comment: No your loop is ok. Most probably issue is that you are not setting `handTotal` to 0 before entering the loop.

Comment: what does the hand list look like before it enters the for loop?

Comment: Actually, the handTotal might be the culprit. EDIT: What I mean is: if handTotal is a class member, you are adding the total of the hand as it grows to the previous total.

Comment: Please explain what makes you think that the code is not working, and show the calling code. At the moment, we're all just guessing as to what might be the problem, but have nothing concrete to work with.

Comment: I actually added a bunch of print statements and deleted them to post this. But for instance I had it print i at the beginning and end and it prints that it equals 0 at top and bottom twice before incrementing i.

Comment: The hand size is dealt with outside of this but this is called after cards are dealt to the hand.

Comment: Perhaps you are calling this method when there is only one card, and then calling again when there are two cards? Resetting handTotal at the start of this method would solve that problem (and is probably a good idea, given that this method is supposed to calculate the total).

Comment: What is in your `List`? Remove the `continue`.

Comment: Where is handTotal being used/declared?

Comment: This is set every time cards are dealt. The List is composed of Card objects.

Comment: SJuan76 / Jason had the right idea. The handTotal is holding the old value calculated from the hand with 1 card and then incremented by the new value from the hand with 2 cards

Comment: Please add a log before the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer a [`for-each`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop to implement `setTotal` (and don't forget to reset the `handTotal` to zero) like

```
private void setTotal() {
    handTotal = 0;
    boolean ace = false;
    for (Card c : hand) {
        int value = c.getValue();
        if (value == 1) {
            ace = true;
        }
        handTotal += (value > 10) ? 10 : value;
    }
    if (ace && handTotal < 12) {
        handTotal += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is my first time taking any Java so can you explain this line
 handTotal += (value > 10) ? 10 : value;

Comment: @Julia It's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java). If value > 10, use 10. Else use value.

Comment: I'm very confused.  I don't see a `continue` statement in her code at all.

Comment: Thank you, initializing handTotal to 0 fixes the problem and I will maybe try a for-each loop although that alone seems to have fixed it.